# Select product from dynamic product page and pass it to other page

Tags: php

I'm developing a website for school. On that website you can find airplanes and their specifications.

Before they will be uploaded to the public page, an admin has to validate them.

This is what I already got:

```
<?php include 'header.php';
if( !$user->admin_is_logged_in() ){ header ('Location: ../../404.php'); exit(); }


$stmt = $dbp->prepare("SELECT * FROM planex_tovalidate ORDER BY planeID DESC");
$stmt-> execute();




?>


<section id="fh5co-about" data-section="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 section-heading text-center">
                <h2 class="to-animate">Uploaded Planes</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 subtext to-animate">
                        <h3>Yeeehaaa! You've got some airplanes in your database! Here are they:</h3>
                        <a href="manage.php">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $planeNAME = $row["planeNAME"];
        $planeTYPE = $row["planeTYPE"];
        $planePHO = $row["planePHO"];
        $manufacturer = $row["manufacturer"];
        $status = $row["status"];
        $firstflight = $row["firstflight"];
        $produced = $row["produced"];
        $addedto = $row["created"];

        echo '

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="fh5co-person text-center to-animate">
                <figure><img src="'. $planePHO .'" alt="PlanePHO"></figure>
                <h3>'. $manufacturer, $planeNAME. '</h3>
                <span class="fh5co-position">Some specs:</span>
    <p> Aircraft Status: '. $status .' <br>
    Aircraft First Flight: '. $firstflight . ' </p>
    <a href="activate_plane.php">Set Active to Planex!</a><br>
    <a href="edit_plane.php">Edit this plane.</a>
    </div>
            </div>';
        }

        ?>

        </div>
</section>

<?php include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Now, I got several questions (note: do I need to make a new question for each question here on Stackoverflow? Or can I ask multiple questions in one topic?)

The first one:
I got some dynamic aircraft. How can I assign a value or unique code to each aircraft, select it if I want to edit it and pass it to the edit_airplane.php file?

The second one: 
How can I, if I got the selected airplane assign a photo to that unique row in my database? (planePHO got a standard photo link in the database). I would like to upload the photo to a folder in my website, and create a link to the photo and pass the link to the database airplane.

My upload code (got it from w3schools):

https://pastebin.com/ZySD0wNb

Thank you for your answer!

(Sorry for my English, it's not that quite good ;) )

Comment: first: You can get the id of the airplane (in database) and send it with $_GET so You know which airplane edit. Second: You should make a second database table airplane_images with the id of each airplane. Because You may need one image for many airplane (this is not possible with single table)

Comment: @MsuArven Thank you for your answer! Can you show me some code how to get the id with $_GET? I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: I added answer. If you need more details don't hesitate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
You need the id of the plane in the edit page (otherwise You cannot know which plane edit):

```
$planeNAME = $row["planeNAME"];
    $planeTYPE = $row["planeTYPE"];
    $planePHO = $row["planePHO"];
    $manufacturer = $row["manufacturer"];
    $status = $row["status"];
    $firstflight = $row["firstflight"];
    $produced = $row["produced"];
    $addedto = $row["created"];
    $id = $row['id']; // the id column


<a href="edit_plane.php?id='.$id.'">Edit this plane.</a>
```

Step 2: In edit_plane.php You get the id like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
var_dump($id); // debug
```